# Hot-spare using Pound

Tags: load-balancing, failover, pound

I currently have a server deployment in which Pound is being used as a reverse proxy (HTTPS -> HTTP) in front of a single server instance.  I'd like to add a second instance on a different host that acts as a hot-spare in the event that the main instance is down for any reason.  I don't want any traffic whatsoever directed to the second server instance when the first instance is up.

From the documentation it seems that adding a second `BackEnd` entry into the `Service` block in `pound.cfg` will cause pound to monitor and load-balance between the two hosts, but I'm not seeing any options that would let me control *how* pound load-balances, or more specifically, instruct pound to *only* use 'host 2' when 'host 1' is down.

Is it possible to do this using pound?  If not, are there any other open-source tools that would be better suited to this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Found the option I was looking for.  The `Service` block can also contain one or more `Emergency` entries for hosts that should only be used if all preceding `BackEnd` nodes are down, which is exactly what I want.

Some good reference material is available here:  https://calomel.org/pound.html